.Net 8 MAUI - Default route for Flyout Tab
I'm working with .Net MAUI and using Shell navigation with this Shell p

List item

age
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="LibraryAppM.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibraryAppM.Views"
    Title="LibraryAppM"
    TitleColor="DarkCyan">
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <Tab Title="Information" Icon="lib_pic.jpg" Route="information">
            <ShellContent
                Title="Home"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
                Icon="home.png"
                Route="home" />
            <ShellContent
                Title="Favourite"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FavouritePage}"
                Icon="favourite.jpeg"
                Route="favourite" />
            <ShellContent
                Title="Recommended"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:RecommendedPage}"
                Icon="lib_pic.jpg"
                Route="recommended" />
            <ShellContent
                Title="Loans"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoansPage}"
                Icon="lib_pic.jpg"
                Route="loans" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Enquiry"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:EnquiryPage}"
        Icon="enquiry.png"
        Route="enquiry" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Search"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SearchPage}"
        Icon="search.png"
        Route="search" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Update"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:UpdatePage}"
        Icon="update.png"
        Route="update" />
</Shell>

When I choose "Information" from the flyout the system takes me to last used of the 4 pages.  So if I have viewed Favourite say and then pick another option such as Enquiry, the system takes me back to the Favourite page again next time I click Information.  Is there a way I can set the route on the Tab so that it always goes to the Home page?

You can use the PropertyChanged to detect the element change. The First Items[0] is the FlyoutItem and the Second Items[0] is the Tab and you can use it to judge if it is the First item in the Tab. If it is not the First item. You can change it to the First.
Here is the code you can refer to:
public AppShell()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>{
          if(e.PropertyName == "CurrentItem")
          {
            if(CurrentItem != Items[0])
              {
                 Items[0].Items[0].CurrentItem = Items[0].Items[0].Items[0];
              }
           }
        };
     }


Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this and it works the first time I return to the flyout but not afterwards when the system crashes withglobal::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Do you have more information about the issue and what did you do to cause the issue？

I've decided to change from a Shell app to one based on a Flyoutpage with a Tabbedpage. This overcomes the problem of Shell reusing pages rather than creating new each time.
